# Can someone recommend a Java ebook maker for mobile on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, java, ebooks

Can someone recommend a Java ebook maker for mobiles? I want to create 176x220 or 240x320 ebooks for my personal use. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I found a couple of softwares for Windows but I don't want to use Wine and windows dlls in my pc.
Thanks

Comment: Why does it need to be in Java?

Comment: Calibre is good, but it's not in Java

Comment: Because I need .jar file for my old style mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Sigil (http://code.google.com/p/sigil/). I don't think Sigil is java based, but I also don't see the problem with this as you can compile sigil on any platform running ubuntu even if it has no x86 based architecture, if this is your problem (but I don't think so as you were talking about installing wine which is only possible when using a x86 based architecture, so you can simply download ).

By the way: Calibre is not a program for making ebooks but for managing and converting it.

If you have a x86 based processor (if windows is able to run on your system, the answer to this question is yes, however you can find out by typing `uname -m` on the command line, if the result contains "86" you have this kind of processor) then you can install sigil from a ppa by typing three commands on the command line:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rgibert/ebook` this will ask you for your password
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install sigil`

Otherwise you could compile it from source.